# Magento 2 - Add Another Provider / Add Data To Provider - Checkout UI Component

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, uicomponent

I want to either add quote data to checkoutProvider so my custom input will use it or add my own provider and tell the input to use that.

How is this done?

Comment: I don't know enough about this to provide an answer, but I know [this page of the dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html) can come in handy - just in case it contains anything that helps you out

Comment: Thank you, I tried that - it doesn't help as per usual. I have figured it out now, if you ever need it.